# first_name property missing inside register_user action hook

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-registration

I'm trying to access the $user->first_name property from a function triggered by the `register_user` action hook but it's not there:

```
function do_stuff($user_id) {

$new_user = get_userdata($user_id);

$first_name1 = $new_user->user_firstname;
$last_name1 = $new_user->user_lastname;
    echo "<" . $first_name1 . $last_name1 . ">";
    //returns: <>

$first_name2 = $new_user-first_name;
$last_name2 = $new_user->last_name;
    echo "<" . $first_name2 . $last_name2 . ">";
    //returns: <>

}
add_action("register_user", "do_stuff");
```

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( $new_user->ID );
var_dump($user_meta);
```

and I got this (last_name and first_name are empty even though they're defined in the user's profile):

```
array(11) { ["wp_user_level"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["show_admin_bar_front"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["wp_capabilities"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}" } ["use_ssl"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["admin_color"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "fresh" } ["comment_shortcuts"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "false" } ["rich_editing"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["description"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["nickname"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "emerson" } ["last_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["first_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some user stuff changed in 3.2 and perhaps user meta works a bit differently now...

```
function do_stuff( $user_id ) {
    $first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
    $last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );
    echo $first_name . $last_name;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'do_stuff' );
```

Comment: I also get nothing from `$first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );` I've had all of these work in the past so I'm totally confused.

Comment: @Emerson - are you sure you're getting nothing? outputting something within non-encoded angle brackets <> will hide it from view in a browser. tested and working for me in TwentyTen theme.

Comment: @Emerson - also verify you are using the correct action, it's `user_register` not `register_user` as in your code example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That was a typo (I'm using `user_register`.

Comment: I updated the question with the output of `get_user_meta()`. (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Ooh. I just re-read your comment and you mentioned TwentyTen theme. *All* the approaches work for me when used in the theme. My problem is that I need them to work inside a (mu-) plugin.

Comment: @Emerson - it shouldn't matter where it's used, it's all hooked to the same action, my point was it's a default install with no potential conflicts between other plugins or theme code. how are you adding these users?

Comment: I see. So you suspect a plugin conflict? Interesting. I'm manually adding users using the registration form, but I am using a plugin called s2Member which does involve users/registration/etc. Do you think s2Member might somehow delay the definition of `first_name` etc?

Comment: @Emerson - it's possible. I believe user meta is cached, so it's possible the cache isn't being refreshed.

Comment: Huh. I submitted a ticket with s2Member, but I'd like to explore the caching idea too. I did a quick search and I didn't see any functions that let me force a refresh. Do you know of any?

Comment: have a look at the [wp object cache page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache). it's just a shot in the dark though.

Answer (score 0):

There has been no new answer to the question for years. Maybe the solution I applied in a similar problem will be useful to you. When Wordpress creates an user, it first creates the user and then creates the meta datas. Therefore, you may not be able to access all information with 'user_register'. You can use the 'profile_update' action instead. This action is fired after the user is created and the last meta data is saved.

```
function my_custom_function ( $user_id ) {

    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $first_name = $user_data->first_name;
    $last_name = $user_data->last_name;

}
add_action('profile_update', 'my_custom_function');
```